# Add leading 0 after the dash (-) but before the numbers

Tags: excel, formula

I have a formula that adds a 0 before the numbers 1-9 if they don't have one.

**Old**..................**New**

D-8..................D-08

FE-09..............FE-09

I-18..................I-18

P-1..................P-01

FG-08A...........FG-08

`=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1))&TEXT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,2),"00")`

However, for values like FG-08A, I do not want it to clear the A at the end. So if it's FG-08A, the result would be FG-08A (remain unchanged). If it's FG-8A, it would be FG-08A (adds the leading 0 but keeps the "A").

Comment: Will you never have more than two consecutive numbers and if yes will these never be `00`? If yes to both questions, you could wrap your formula in a `Substitute` so change `00` to `0`

Comment: Do you have values like `D-8A` which you want to change to `D-08A`?  (side note, your current formula already fails to handle these)

Comment: @chrisneilsen I only have double letters before the hyphen when there is a letter at the end (ex: LF-32C, LB-09A, etc.)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad No, I never have more than two consecutive numbers. It will never be 00, and I'm not sure I understand how I can use Substitute in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add check for the ending letter:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1))&TEXT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,2))+1),"00")&IF(ISERROR(--RIGHT(A1)),RIGHT(A1),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, if you never have more than two consecutive numbers and if these will never be `00`, you can use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","-0"),"00","0")
```